# Video tag in jsp page using jstl

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can I use `<video>` tag for my spring application in jsp page with jstl tags

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>

<html>
<head>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/main.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
        $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');          

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
          else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
        })
    });

</script>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
    <nav>
        <h1>CHALLENGER</h1>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
            <source src="C:\\Users\\ratheesh\\Downloads\Linux\\LinuxInspires.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <ul>
            <li id="login"><a id="login-trigger" href="#"> Log in <span></span>
            </a>
                <div id="login-content">
                    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                        <div class="error">${error}</div>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                    </c:if>

                    <form name='loginForm'
                        action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

                        <fieldset id="inputs">

                            <input type='text' name='username' id="username"
                                placeholder="Your email address" required> <input
                                type='password' name='password' id="password"
                                placeholder="Password" required>

                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset id="actions">
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
                            <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                                Keep me signed in</label>

                        </fieldset>

                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    </form>
                </div></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering why this is not loading video on my jsp page
when I put the same video tag in stand alone html page it is working
Any help will be appreciated highly

Comment: Your video location should be relative to the deployed url -- to the page itself, not referencing a file location relative to your own machine's HD.

Comment: Following too not working   <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
     <source src="../LinuxInspires.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>

Comment: Finally got resolved. Added .In my app static resources were loading like <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />   So put video inside thisfolder and  changed code as follows <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
     <source src="<c:url value="/resources/LinuxInspires.mp4" />" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>